# How to edit a field in MySQL, where fieldData='String' to new value of 'String.a'?

Tags: database, mysql

In my database there is a field in type VARCHAR (let's name in field1), in some cases, I want to find special record and edit the value of field1, my query must be able to read the current value of field1 and add special string like ".a" at the end of it. I guess the query must be something like this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET field1 = CurrentValue +'a' WHERE field1 = CurrentValue ;
```

but its not complete, and there is error. Would you help me?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `SET field1 = CONCAT(field1,'a')`

The procedure you said you got an error for works for me:

```
mysql> create database test;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test.Files (Name text) select 'MyFile' Name;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE test.Rename (CurrentName Text) BEGIN UPDATE test.Files SET Name = CONCAT(Name , 'a') WHERE Name = CurrentName; END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> call test.Rename('MyFile');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test.Files;
+---------+
| Name    |
+---------+
| MyFilea |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: TNX for your answer, I ran this:  "UPDATE tableName SET field1 = CONCAT(field1,'a') WHERE field1='DesiredString';  "     and I got this error:    "Error Code: 1292
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a'   "

Comment: I think it is because of your column type. What is the type of Column Field1? What's your varchar length you have defined? perhaps it's exceeding that.

Comment: @rain: that (misleading) error can sometimes result from bad syntax; can you show the exact statement you are running, without replacing the table, column, and values with generic substitutions?

Comment: @rain: you have a procedure named Rename but you are calling one named Files?  also, are you sure you created the procedure in the test database, not some other?

Comment: I'm sorry, the call statement that I,ve wrot here was wrong, the main call statement is true: 'call test.rename('MyFile');', I'm sure that the problem is not in calling or selecting database, I have almost 15 tables and 12 routine that all of them work properly. Now my rename procedure has 2 arguments, it gets 'CurrentName' and 'NewName', and I've used this command in the routine body: 'SET Name = NewName WHERE Name = CurrentName.' and in my program I've put something like this NewName := CurrentName+'a' It works for me, But I'm confused how this works 'SET F1=CONCAT(F1,'a')'Have you tested it

Comment: @rain: yes, I tested that SET clause in an update statement, and the procedure you showed worked for me, on mysql 5.1.41

Comment: You mean the procedure with 2 arguments worked for you? The one that has 2 argument works for me too. would you put me the complete procedure that you've tested which contains 'SET F1=CONCAT(F1,'a')'?        TNX.

Comment: @rain: no, you didn't show the 2-argument procedure.  the one argument one worked for me; I've added it to my answer ^

Comment: Tnx a lot. So I'll try it directly in MySQL, in some parts I've done my job in some MySQL interfaces, maybe there was a bug in in the interface, Tnx again :)